# How i can do a drawer like this on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-drawer

I am trying to archive this kind of drawer

[image]

Comment: It is better to show your effort what you’ve tried so far.   Make an honest attempt at the solution yourself, show it to us, tell what went wrong and we'll be able to help - [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a container and decoration to it like

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      
      home: MyWidget(),

    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
     drawer: Drawer(
       elevation: 0,
       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
       child: Container(
         decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.4),
            borderRadius :BorderRadius.only(bottomRight:Radius.circular(150))
         )
       )
     ),
      body: Text("asdfasdfasdf")
    );
  }

 
}
```

[image: preview]